# Solving $\log_{1/3} \left(x^3 - 1\right) > \log_{1/3} \left(|3x^2 - 3x|\right)$

Tags: inequality

I tried over and over again but I simply can't solve:
$$\log_{1/3} \left(x^3 - 1\right) > \log_{1/3} \left(|3x^2 - 3x|\right)$$

So, if someone could please explain to me how to solve this step by step, I would be very greatful. By the way, the solution for this problem is $x \in \varnothing$.

---

**Edit**

This is what I tried to do:

$$\log_\frac{1}{3} \left(x^3 - 1\right) > \log_\frac{1}{3} \left(|3x^2 - 3x|\right) $$

to find the domain

$$\begin{cases} 
x^3-1>0 \implies x^3>1 \implies x>\sqrt[3] 1 \implies x>1 \\
3x^2 - 3x>0 \implies \ldots \implies x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)\\
-3x^2 + 3x<0 \implies \ldots \implies x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)
\end{cases}$$

then domain is $x>1$.

We need to solve

$$x^3 - 1 <|3x^2 - 3x| \implies 
\begin{cases} 
x^3 - 1 <3x^2 - 3x \quad (1)\\
x^3 - 1 <-3x^2 + 3x \quad (2)
\end{cases}$$

from $(1)$ we otain

$$x^3 -3x^2 + 3x-1<0 \implies x<1$$

from $(2)$ we otain

$$x^3 +3x^2 - 3x-1<0  \implies x\in(-\infty,-2-\sqrt 3)\cup(-2-\sqrt 3,1)$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please show us your work so far.  The easiest method might be taking a picture and sharing the picture.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I tried solving the inequation and solving the domain of the logarithms, but I am not certain of how to link those two into an answer. And I am not certain if I solved the inequation or the domain correctly. Because I have never seen an inequation with a logarithm before and I just tried to figure out what to do with the help of YouTube videos.

Comment: It is an inequality, not an inequation

Comment: @FShrike What is the difference?

Comment: Inequation, as far as I know, is not an English word and I have never seen it in the hundreds of maths articles and resources that I’ve viewed. The standard word is just “inequality”

Comment: @FShrike Uhm, what about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequation. It does exist, albeit the word inequality might be more common.

Comment: Well, that’s completely a new one on me. My apologies for challenging you. Inequation to me could make sense only as a statement like $x\neq y$, but even then it sounds strange

Comment: Let try to write down your work using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it is a very useful tool to learn also for you.

Comment: @MarcoTrevino I've translate your work from paper in MathJax, take a look to confirm it correspond to your work. Your work is almost fine with this obseravtion: a) For the domain, for the last two conditions we need and it suffices to check $3x^2 - 3x \neq 0$ (the third condittion is equivalent to the second); b) The inequality $(2)$ is wrong because for the given domain $3x^2 - 3x > 0$.

Comment: @user Thank you for translating my work into MathJax and for giving me further explenations to help me solve this problem. But your answer to my post really was everything that I needed to be able to decipher this problem. P.S. I know the basics of MathJax but I uploaded a picture of my work instead because I didn't have enough time to type everything in MathJax.

Comment: @MarcoTrevino You are welcome! For the next time try to write down things in MathJax, it is better for searching in the site and also your question would be better perceived in that way. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $\log_{\frac 13}x$ function is strictly decreasing then

$$\log_\frac{1}{3} \left(x^3 - 1\right) > \log_\frac{1}{3} \left(|3x^2 - 3x|\right) \iff x^3 - 1 <|3x^2 - 3x|$$

under the conditions

- $x^3 - 1>0 \iff x>1$
- $|3x^2 - 3x| \neq 0 \iff x\neq 0 \quad x \neq 1$

that is $x>1$ therefore

$$x^3 - 1 <|3x^2 - 3x| \iff x^3 - 1 <3x^2 - 3x \iff x^3-3x^2+3x - 1=(x-1)^3<0$$